# ODBC with active directory password authentication using a login ID and password not configurable

Tags: authentication, sql-server, odbc, ssms

The server `MYSERVER` holds the SQL database `MyDatabase`. The account `MYCOMPANY\myaccount` is registered for `MyDatabase` with server roles `public` and `sysadmin` and with permission `Connect SQL` granted by `sa`. Login to *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)* works fine with *Windows Authentication* for `MYCOMPANY\myaccount`.

However, configuration of an *ODBC*-connection as summarized in the images fails for a user logged into a local account on a client PC. `MYSERVER` is accessible for `MYCOMPANY\myaccount` from the local account, e. g. with *Remote Desktop Connection*. In *SSMS*, the Server authentication option `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode` is activated (see [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923015/login-to-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456)). What might be missing to enable *ODBC*-configuration in this case?

Technical facts:

- Server: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- SQL Server Version: 14.0.2027.2
- SSMS Version: v18.4
- Client: Windows 10 Pro 20H2

[image: odbc_configuration]